# Markdown in Activity posts?

Tags: trello, markdown

Card descriptions in Trello can accept markdown syntax, but Activity comments seem to be plain text only. Is there some setting I can change to allow Markdown in activity comments as well?

Answer (score 9):

No, there isn't a setting.

Trello does not (currently) support markdown in comments.